# How to solve this Error: Cannot find module 'ibm-watson'

Tags: node.js, node-modules, ibm-watson

I have installed ibm-watson using "npm install ibm-watson" command
I can see the folder and its file in the node_modules folder, but still showing this error.
Node version - v10.15.3

```
const watson = require('ibm-watson');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');
const { BasicAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

// to get an IAM Access Token
const authorization = new watson.AuthorizationV1({
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({ apikey: 'fakekey-1234' }),
});

authorization.getToken(function (err, token) {
  if (!token) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
  } else {
    // Use your token here
  }
});
```

Other modules are importing fine, Only this module not importing.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ibm-watson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

Comment: Not really a solution, but have you tried deleting the npm mods and running npm i just to see what happens?

Comment: Please show the code that is failing.

Comment: Yes I deleted node_modules and installed again, Still, I am getting the error@anna

Comment: @works_as_coded , const watson = require('ibm-watson');
This is the code getting error

Comment: You need to specify which submodule(s) you want to import. I encourage you to look at the examples [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/examples)

Comment: @works_as_coded But i have checked the usage they gave in thier document and added the code Ex:
`const watson = require('ibm-watson');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');
const { BasicAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

// to get an IAM Access Token
const authorization = new watson.AuthorizationV1({
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({ apikey: 'fakekey-1234' }),
});

authorization.getToken(function (err, token) {
  if (!token) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
  } else {
    // Use your token here
  }
});`

Comment: You cannot import the base package because there is nothing exported from it. Remove the line `const watson = require('ibm-watson');`, it is not needed.

Comment: @works_as_coded Removed, Instead which one I have to add?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you are trying to accomplish. What happens when you run the code now? What do want to happen?

Comment: @works_as_coded I need to get token for access speech to text - (Microphone stream)

Comment: This code will consume that token, `var stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone({
                token: token,
                objectMode: true,
                format: false
            });
            stream.on('data', function(data) {}); `

Comment: Add this to your else branch: `console.log('token:', token)`. Run it. Do you have a token?

Comment: No, token will generate by above node module, I can't generate token because of that error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207367/discussion-between-sathiesh-kumar-and-works-as-coded).

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced this issue. I did not install the correct version of the package. Please check the [apidocs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding?code=node) for Node to see the correct version of IBM Watson npm package that you need. for me I needed 5.6.0.

You can install it with the following command:

`npm install ibm-watson@^5.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting a token, I am going to guess that you are using Speech To Text. As the comments have suggested the failing line is `const watson = require('ibm-watson');` because it isn't exported. Instead you would use, as per the API documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text/speech-to-text?code=node#authentication:

```js
const SpeechToTextV1 = require('ibm-watson/speech-to-text/v1');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');
const { IamTokenManager } = require('ibm-watson/auth');
```

If it's not STT that you are using then the other services work the same way when requiring `ibm-watson`. Links to the API Docs can be found here - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

After reading the code, I understood.

There is only `sdk.ts` file, not `index.ts`  file.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk

```
// const watson = require('ibm-watson');
const watson = require('ibm-watson/sdk');
```

But I still got the error.

Eventually it worked if I wrote the following

```
import AuthorizationV1 from 'ibm-watson/authorization/v1'
import { IamAuthenticator } from 'ibm-watson/auth'

const apikey = '********'
const authorization = new AuthorizationV1({
  url: 'https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token',
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({ apikey }),
})

authorization.getToken(function (err, token) {
  if (!token) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
  } else {
    // Use your token here
  }
});
```

But there is a CORS problem. I don't know any more.

[image]

The answer was written here. I need to do it on the server side

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/issues/884#issuecomment-515050023